# How to set the animated character's position on the grid floor?

Tags: animation, constraints, path

I already animated the action for the character, just realise that the character in the middle of the grid floor, My question is how can i set the character on the grid floor instead of inserting keyframe one by one

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "set the character on the grid floor"? If the character is not on the right place, switch to Object mode and move the armature. Also you need to understand that within one action you can keyframe both the armature and the bones themselves, which can lead to some mistakes like the one you've made previously

Comment: Select the root bone, go to the Graph Editor, select all keyframes of its "Y Location" channel (double click on the channel's name) and move them up.